# Error: Permissions not granted... react-native-image-picker

Tags: android, gradle, react-native, android-studio-2.3

I am trying to upload an image from internal memory in our client app, using

> *react-native-image-picker@^0.26.4*

And after executing the following sample snippet i got the response in an unexpected way.

```
ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, response => {
  console.log("Response = ", response)

  if (response.didCancel) {
    console.log("User cancelled image picker")
  } else if (response.error) {
    console.log("ImagePicker Error: ", response.error)
  } else if (response.customButton) {
    console.log("User tapped custom button: ", response.customButton)
  } else {
    const source = { uri: response.uri }
    // RNGRP.getRealPathFromURI(response.uri).then(filePath => {
    //   uploadImageToS3(filePath, "dinesh")
    //   console.log(filePath)
    // })

    // You can also display  the image using data:
    // let source = { uri: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + response.data };

    this.setState({
      avatarSource: source
    })
  }
```

## RESPONSE

- Response =  {error: "Permissions weren't granted"}
  error: "Permissions weren't granted"**proto**: Object
  D:\my_app\index.js:124 ImagePicker Error:  Permissions weren't granted
- Sometimes On Allow button press app unexpectedly crashes.

## Additional Information

- React Native version: ~0.46.1
- React: 16.0.0-alpha.12
- Platform: [Android 5.1 and above]
- Development Operating System: [Windows 7 Professional]
- Dev tools: [ Android Studio version 2.3.2, Android SDK 23]

Comment: I think you should add some permissions in your manifest file([android permission](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html)).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Add this code in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Edited this after suggestions by Jaffar Raza and szskdgi

Comment: **FALSE AND MISLEADING** - there is no such permission as "android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE"

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

should be replaced with 

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: Please edit the answer with WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. I tried internal and got stuck for a while there.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer won't work if you are using Android M or API level 23+, You need to prompt the user for permission.

Add this code in the `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifiest.xml`

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

App.js

```js
const App=()=>{
   useEffect(() => {
    requestPermission()
  }, [])

  const requestPermission = async () => {
    try {
      console.log('asking for permission')
      const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.requestMultiple(
        [PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE]
      )
      if (granted['android.permission.CAMERA'] && granted['android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE']) {
        console.log("You can use the camera");
      } else {
        console.log("Camera permission denied");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('permission error', error)
    }
  }
  ....

}
```

For detailed implementation and a list of permission that require prompting the user

https://reactnative.dev/docs/permissionsandroid

Answer (score 1):

Add this code in the android/app/src/main/AndroidManifiest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

after adding the following permission to AndroidManifiest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

we should have checked the permission before processing the functionality.

ex :-
step 1(check permission whether it's GRANTED or not)

```
const isCameraAuthorized = await permissions.checkPermission(
          PermissionType.CAMERA
        );
enter code here
```

step 2(request permission)

```
 cameraPermissionStatus = await permissions.requestPermission(
            PermissionType.CAMERA
          );
```

then we have do the same for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE as

```
cameraPermissionStatus = await permissions.requestPermission(
                PermissionType.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE 
              );
 const isCameraAuthorized = await permissions.checkPermission(
              PermissionType.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE 
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

I took "user didnt grant library permisson" message
in some devices
while I had added  this permisson

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

so I changed to

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  package="com.app.name">
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="29" tools:replace="android:maxSdkVersion" />
```

and worked after change

Answer (score 0):

in my case,

My React native,targetSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion version  is

```
"react-native": "0.62.2"
.....
 compileSdkVersion = 33
 targetSdkVersion = 33
```

and the latest `react-native-image-picker=5.4.0` is not compatible with this version

so that I'm using

```
  "react-native-image-picker": "^3.0.0",
```

and this version work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:  Install package react native permissions

Step 2:  Add the below code in the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES"/>
```

Step 3: Add the line inside AndroidManifest.xml and add in the application section:

android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"

Step 4: Add inside index.js file:

PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.CAMERA;