# App crashes when using react-native-image-picker

Tags: react-native

App crashes when selecting either of the two options on the dialog box ('Take photo' or 'Select from Library') using react-native-image-picker.

**Additional Information**

- React Native version: 0.55.3
- react-native-image-picker version: 0.26.7

This is the function for showing image picker

```
_showImagePicker(userImageType) {
    const isImage = userImageType != 'videoUrl';
    var options = {
        title: translate(isImage ? 'PROFILE_EDITOR_SELECT_IMAGE' : 'PROFILE_EDITOR_SELECT_VIDEO'),
        cancelButtonTitle: translate('IMAGE_PICKER_CANCEL_BUTTON_TITLE'),
        takePhotoButtonTitle: translate('IMAGE_PICKER_TAKE_PHOTO_BUTTON_TITLE'),
        chooseFromLibraryButtonTitle: translate('IMAGE_PICKER_FROM_LIBRARY_BUTTON_TITLE'),
        mediaType: userImageType != 'videoUrl' ? 'photo' : 'video',
        noData: 'true',
        videoQuality: 'low',
        storageOptions: {
            skipBackup: true,
            path: 'captures'
        }
    };
    ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
        console.log('Response = ', response);
        if (response.didCancel) {
            return;
        }
        else if (response.error) {
            Alert.alert(response.error);
            return;
        }
        else {
            let source = response.uri;
            if (userImageType != 'videoUrl' && response.fileSize > (6 * 1024 * 1024)) {
                Alert.alert(translate("DEFAULT_ERROR_TITLE"), translate('PROFILE_EDITOR_IMAGE_SIZE_EXCEEEDS_MAX'));
                return;
            }
            // You can also display the image using data:
            // let source = {uri: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + response.data };
            if (userImageType != 'videoUrl') {
                this._processProfileData(userImageType, source);
            } else {
                // Updated. Adapted to new server format
                this._processProfileData(userImageType, source)
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**logger:**

> 05-30 11:33:15.481  8285  8359 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules
>   05-30 11:33:15.481  8285  8359 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.tripbru.tripper.dev, PID: 8285
>   05-30 11:33:15.481  8285  8359 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
>   05-30 11:33:15.481  8285  8359 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReadableNativeMap.getBoolean(ReadableNativeMap.java:137)
>   05-30 11:33:15.481  8285  8359 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.imagepicker.ImagePickerModule.parseOptions(ImagePickerModule.java:708)
>   05-30 11:33:15.481  8285  8359 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.imagepicker.ImagePickerModule.launchImageLibrary(ImagePickerModule.java:321)
>   05-30 11:33:15.481  8285  8359 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.imagepicker.ImagePickerModule.launchImageLibrary(ImagePickerModule.java:302)
>   05-30 11:33:15.481  8285  8359 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.imagepicker.ImagePickerModule$2.onUseLibrary(ImagePickerModule.java:172)
>   05-30 11:33:15.481  8285  8359 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.imagepicker.utils.UI$1.onClick(UI.java:58)
>   05-30 11:33:15.481  8285  8359 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:1044)

Comment: Have you added the correct permissions?

Comment: Paste some code we can't read your mind!

Comment: @GavinThomas Yes i already added the permissions.

Comment: provide your logger

Comment: See link for correct permissions

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45711011/error-permissions-not-granted-react-native-image-picker/45711204

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue ?